# How to restrict the minting in pallet-nft?

Tags: substrate-node-template, nft

We need to find a way to restrict the minting in the nft pallet so only certain accounts can mint a nft or can create a collection. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Referring to `pallet-nfts`, for creating a collection you have the [`CreateOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs#L129-L135) ([see here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs#L685)). For minting nfts it depends on the config of your collection, more specifically the [`MintType`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/nfts/src/types.rs#L291-L302).

You can find this yourself when you look at the source code of a pallet in `polkadot-sdk/substrate/frame/<pallet>`, in your case the extrinsics `fn create` and `fn mint` in [`pallet-nfts`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs).